# Why I continue to receive the "gnome-session-binary"?

Tags: gnome, unity, canon, session, startup-applications

I'm using Ubuntu `Linux X40 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC`  and `GNOME Shell 42.9`

The output of `journalctl -xe | grep "gnome-session-binary"`:

```
set 27 07:26:35 X40 gnome-session[1074]: gnome-session-binary[1074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
set 27 07:26:35 X40 gnome-session[1074]: gnome-session-binary[1074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
set 27 07:26:35 X40 gnome-session-binary[1074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
set 27 07:26:35 X40 gnome-session-binary[1074]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
set 27 07:26:52 X40 gnome-session-binary[1074]: Entering running state
set 27 07:27:18 X40 systemd[1507]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:18 X40 systemd[1507]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:18 X40 systemd[1507]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:18 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:18 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session-binary[1664]: Entering running state
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session[1664]: gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1853: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1853 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1853: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1853 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session[1664]: gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1912: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1912 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1912: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1912 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session[1664]: gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1916: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1916 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 gnome-session-binary[1664]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 1916: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 1916 does not exist.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:27:23 X40 gnome-session-binary[1074]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
set 27 07:27:23 X40 gnome-session[1074]: gnome-session-binary[1074]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
set 27 07:28:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
set 27 07:28:21 X40 systemd[1507]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
```

Comment: Please use [code block]s to format commands and output. Quote formatting badly mangles them and it's not possible for us to fix it.

Comment: It's better now or need more details or modifications?

Comment: It's worse. You should get the original output and use code formatting for _that_, instead of code formatting the quote formatted mess.

Comment: What can I do to improve the answer and the question?

Comment: Thanks, the formatting looks perfect now! If the problem went away just by upgrading and rebooting, the question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rebooted and use the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and the problem was solved. The command `journalctl -xe | grep "gnome-canary-session"`  don't return nothing after this.